# Conditionally setting array variable type

Tags: java, arrays, types, conditional-statements, primitive

I'm creating a Java program that will graphically display points.
The coordinates are read from a .txt File and stored in an appropriately-typed array, `int[]` or `double[]`.

The following code illustrates what I'm wanting. (Though it doesn't work because `Array` is not the superclass of `int[]` and `double[]`.)

```
//Declare local variable
Array coordinates;

//Determine data type
if(scan.hasNextInt()){
    coordinates = int[10];
} else if(scan.hasNextDouble()){
    coordinates = double[10];
}
```

I was thinking of using polymorphism, as you can see, but I don't know what the superclass of `int[]` and `double[]` is. What is their superclass? Or is there a better way to do this conditional typing? If I use the Object superclass to declare `coordinates`, then it will not function as an array.

---

This is for an assignment. The details for what I'm trying to solve here are as follows:

> The program reads the values [of the text file], **converting them to
>   integers or doubles as appropriate**, storing them internally in an
>   array.

I interpreted that to mean the array should be of the type it is storing, but maybe it is simply saying to store the values in an array as numerical values instead of the original `String` type...

Comment: Can you explain more about your problem, are you willing to store `int` and `double` values that you read from a file into one array that contains both types?

Comment: you should use     double, no need for     int type.

Comment: The superclass of `int[]` and `double[]` is `Object`, not that it will help you in any way. The approach you're trying won't work, are you sure you've understood your assignment properly? You could switch to wrapper classes and use a `Number[]`, but that's not a great solution either (although sometimes teachers give out poorly thought out assignments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a double array, it will be able to contain both integers and doubles:

```
    double[] coordinates = new double[10];

    coordinates[0] = 1.5; //double
    coordinates[1] = 2;   //integer
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! That's what I would normally do, but this is for a course and the assignment details read: The program reads the values, converting them to integers or doubles (floating point) as appropriate, storing them internally in an array.

Comment: @MichelleB. that assignment doesn't prohibit using this answer. It says nothing about the type of the array.

Comment: @Kayaman Thank you for pointing this out. You're right. I made it more complicated than it really was.

Answer (score 0):

There is no superclass for java primitive types - they are not Objects.  However, autoboxing will convert them, so you can just use an array of Number, which is the superclass for the numeric Classes:

```
  Number[] numbers = new Number[3];
```

then:

```
  numbers[0] = 1.5f;
  numbers[1] = 1;
  numbers[2] = 3.2d;

  for (Number n : numbers)
     log.info("Type: "+n.getClass().getName());
```

will return:

```
Type: java.lang.Float
Type: java.lang.Integer
Type: java.lang.Double
```